# clauses ignored in left outer join sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble with an sql query. The below query returns the rights result. It returns the members in the table that are male, speak swedish and are in group 4.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Member.ID 
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN Experience ON Experience.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Qualification ON Qualification.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Language On Language.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Member_Interests ON Member_Interests.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Group_Members ON Group_Members.MemberID = Member.ID
WHERE 1=1 AND Gender = 'male' AND Language.Name IN ( 'Swedish' ) AND Group_Members.GroupID = 4
```

However if I exclude the other where criteria that search directly on the members table then the language.Name is simply ignored. Ie.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Member.ID 
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN Experience ON Experience.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Qualification ON Qualification.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Language On Language.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Member_Interests ON Member_Interests.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Group_Members ON Group_Members.MemberID = Member.ID
WHERE 1=1 AND Language.Name IN ( 'Swedish' ) AND Group_Members.GroupID = 4
```

The above query returns all members that are in group 4. The Swedish part is simply ignored and as long as there is a langauge in the Langauges table called Swedish then all users are returned. If the language is not in the table then no users are returned.

I would like the second query to just return all members in group 4 that speak swedish. Does anyone know why this is not happening?

Comment: Why do you have a 1=1 where condition?

Comment: I can take a guess: `WHERE 1=1` is in the base SQL, `AND Gender = 'male'`, `AND Language.Name IN ( 'Swedish' )`, `AND Group_Members.GroupID = 4` are dynamically added based on user input.

Comment: no it just makes it easier to comment stuff out during development when each part of the WHERE clause starts with "AND ..." on a different line thereafter. #truestory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the filters on the left joined tables to the joins.

eg:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Language On Language.MemberID = Member.ID 
     and LanguageID in ('Swedish')
LEFT OUTER JOIN Group_Members ON Group_Members.MemberID = Member.ID 
     AND Group_Members.GroupID = 4 
...
WHERE 1=1 AND Gender = 'male'
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with inner join?

or just

```
SELECT DISTINCT Member.ID 
FROM Member, Language
LEFT OUTER JOIN Experience ON Experience.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Qualification ON Qualification.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Member_Interests ON Member_Interests.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Group_Members ON Group_Members.MemberID = Member.ID
WHERE 1=1 AND Gender = 'male' AND Language.MemberID = Member.ID AND Language.Name IN ( 'Swedish' ) AND Group_Members.GroupID = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

clarification:  what do you ULTIMATELY want because LEFT JOINs imply no matter what for the left-side table and WHERE condition, but grab even if nothing on the right side table.  When adding a right-side table into a where, it in effect creates as an inner join.  Do you only want explicitly Males, Language Swedish and Group 4?  If so, I would do with normal joins

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      M.ID 
   FROM Member M
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Experience E
         ON M.ID = E.MemberID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Qualification Q
         ON M.ID = Q.MemberID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Language L 
         ON M.ID = L.MemberID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Member_Interests MI
         ON M.ID = MI.MemberID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Group_Members GM
         ON M.ID = GM.MemberID 
   WHERE 
          1=1 
      AND M.Gender = 'male' 
      AND L.Name IN ( 'Swedish' ) 
      AND GM.GroupID = 4
```

is virtually changing from LEFT JOINs to INNER JOIN is getting ONLY records where Gender is male, and language is swedish and group is 4.  To help better understand and swap the query a bit, I show the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      M.ID 
   FROM Member M
      JOIN Language L 
         ON M.ID = L.MemberID 
         AND L.Name IN ('Swedish')
      JOIN Group_Members GM
         ON M.ID = GM.MemberID 
        AND GM.GroupID = 4
   WHERE 
          1=1 
      AND M.Gender = 'male'
```

I've removed the other LEFT JOIN entries as they had no bearing on the final request of distinct member "ID" values being returned.  why join if not using.

Answer (score 0):

If your previous query was giving right results. Then this one must work for you as you need

```
SELECT DISTINCT Member.ID 
FROM Member
LEFT OUTER JOIN Experience ON Experience.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Qualification ON Qualification.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Language On Language.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Member_Interests ON Member_Interests.MemberID = Member.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Group_Members ON Group_Members.MemberID = Member.ID
WHERE 1=1 AND Gender IN ('male','female') AND Language.Name IN ( 'Swedish' ) 
AND Group_Members.GroupID = 4;
```

Try It, if any problem. Comment Please, otherwise enjoy it :)

Comment: Nick if you are there check my answer. Tell me about it please. I think its good chance to have some positive value in answering rep